# Issues when passing data from parent to child component right after fetching data from API. (functional components only)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to pass data that was fetched from an API to a child functional component. Below, you'll see the steps I followed in my unsuccessful try.

This is the *parent* component that is fetching data from a random API:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import SideMenu from '../Components/SideMenu';

export default function ProductsPage() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all';
    const data = await fetch(url);
    const items = await data.json();
    setProducts(items);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <SideMenu prods={products} />;
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is the *child* component that should be receiving the props from the parent. This cannot be changed:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function SideMenu(props) {
  const [products2, setProducts2] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setProducts2(props.prods);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(products2)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am struggling to figure out why I am **not** getting the desired data in the child component. I'll be thankful if you help me with this one.

P.S.: I am not allowed to use class components, and the child component cannot be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child component does `setProducts2(props.prods);` in an effect hook, very soon after it's mounted, before the parent's `fetch` has finished. At that point, the `prods` will be the initial products in the parent component: the empty array.

The right way to do this would usually be to remove the state from the child component, and use only the props instead - *or*, at least, to call `setProducts2` every time `props.prods` changes (using the dependency array). But if the child component can't be change, neither of those is possible.

But, you can, in the parent component, conditionally render the `SideMenu` only once the response has come back, ensuring that the initial props passed to `SideMenu` contain all the necessary data:

```
  return (
    <div>
      {products.length && <SideMenu prods={products} />}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Such a simple solution and it worked blissfully! Thank you so much! Appreciate it!

Comment: And I do appreciate you took your time to explain to me the whole mechanism. Have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `useEffect` and `useState` in your child component if this is being stored in the parent.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function SideMenu(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(props.prods)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: He says *the child component cannot be changed.*, unfortunately. Weird requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that requirement unless it's some sort of school problem.

Comment: Actually, they just complicated a simple solution and didn't allow me to remove the `useEffect` and `useState`. I couldn't show the full component to explain it better, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to use useEffect in the child component and update it whenever props change.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function SideMenu(props) {
  const [products2, setProducts2] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setProducts2(props.prods);
  }, [props.prods]);

  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(products2)}
    </div>
  );
}
```